# Dúvida sobre alternativa para diminuir tamanho do código e fazer menos consultas

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo, desempenho

estou com um dúvida referente uma certa parte de um sistema que estou desenvolvendo. O sistema é para gerenciamento de uma instituição de ensino superior e tem uma página que é para administrar os cursos da instituição e coloquei alguns filtros via select com auto submit usando javascript, e fiz um sistema de paginação.

A minha dúvida é: Qual alternativa eu tenho para diminuir o meu código, pois achei que ficou muito grande e creio que tenha outras formas de se fazer isso com menos linhas e menos consultas no banco de dados. Do jeito que está tenho que sempre fazer duas consultas no bd, uma para paginação e outra para exibição de resultados

Segue o código:

```
//Abrindo conexao com banco de dados
$con=conectar();

if(isset($_GET)){

    //Recebe número da pagina, caso não exista recebe valor 1
    $pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? filter_var($_GET['pg'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : 1;

    //Variaveis
    $polo = isset($_GET['polo']) ? filter_var($_GET['polo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : null;
    $tipo = isset($_GET['tipo']) ? filter_var($_GET['tipo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : null;

    //Config paginação
    $limite = 2;
    $inicio = ($pg*$limite) - $limite;

                    if($tipo == "" && $polo != "") {

                        $puxa_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE polo = :polo ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite");
                        $puxa_cursos->bindValue(":polo", $polo);
                        $puxa_cursos->execute();

                        //Contar cursos para paginação
                        $contar_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE polo = :polo");
                        $contar_cursos->bindValue(":polo", $polo);
                        $contar_cursos->execute();

                    }else if($polo == "" && $tipo != "") {

                        $puxa_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE tipo = :tipo ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite");
                        $puxa_cursos->bindValue(":tipo", $tipo);
                        $puxa_cursos->execute();

                        //Contando cursos para paginação
                        $contar_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE tipo = :tipo");
                        $contar_cursos->bindValue(":tipo", $tipo);
                        $contar_cursos->execute();

                    }else if ($polo == "" && $tipo == "") {

                        $puxa_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite");
                        $puxa_cursos->execute();

                        //Contando cursos para paginação
                        $contar_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos");
                        $contar_cursos->execute();

                    }else {

                        $puxa_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE polo = :polo AND tipo = :tipo ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite");
                        $puxa_cursos->bindValue(":polo", $polo);
                        $puxa_cursos->bindValue(":tipo", $tipo);
                        $puxa_cursos->execute();

                        //Contando registros para paginação
                        $contar_cursos=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE polo = :polo AND tipo = :tipo");
                        $contar_cursos->bindValue(":polo", $polo);
                        $contar_cursos->bindValue(":tipo", $tipo);
                        $contar_cursos->execute();
                    }

    //Criar array para guardar resultados
    $cursos = array();

    //Enquanto tiver resultados correspondentes, armazena no array
    while($row_cursos=$puxa_cursos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $cursos[] = array(
            'id' => $row_cursos['id'],
            'nome' => utf8_encode($row_cursos['nome']),
                            'tipo' => $row_cursos['tipo'],
            'polo' => $row_cursos['polo']
    );

}

    //Calcula quantidade de paginas com arredondamento para cima
    $paginas = ceil($contar_cursos->rowCount() / $limite);



}
```

Comment: Realmente tem várias coisas que podem ser diminuidas no seu código, mas ajudaria você explicar melhor qual a razão das duas consultas. O fato de ser uma consulta paginada não justifica os dois SELECTs que você faz em cada caso. Também não há necessidade de repetir este monte de prepare e bind, poderia ser um conjunto só e mudar as strings (quem sabe com um mero placeholder no caso em que o polo ou tipo for vazio). Vale a pena conhecer a função COUNT do SQL para quando quiser contar o número de resultados, sem precisar retorná-los.

Comment: Outra coisa é que realmente é quase sempre bom preferir _binding_ do que concatenação de _strings_, mas em alguns casos esta última pode ser mais interessante para um código mais enxuto (desde que devidamente sanitizada); Com MySQLi você tem bindings reais que evitam injeção, mas com PDO no modo _default_ no fim tudo vira concatenação mesmo, então não teria grande perda se tiver os devidos cuidados com sanitização.

Comment: Bacco, obrigado pelas dicas eu estava usando a função count equivocadamente. Tem tempo que eu não programava em php rsrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pode utilizar seu if para definir qual será a consulta e por fim realizá-la, também pode usar funções do próprio mysql para contar o valor da sua consulta ao invés de realizar uma nova, ex;

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET)){

    //Recebe número da pagina, caso não exista recebe valor 1
    $pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? filter_var($_GET['pg'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : 1;

    //Variaveis
    $polo = isset($_GET['polo']) ? filter_var($_GET['polo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : null;
    $tipo = isset($_GET['tipo']) ? filter_var($_GET['tipo'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) : null;

    //Config paginação
    $limite = 2;
    $inicio = ($pg*$limite) - $limite;

    if(!empty($polo) && empty($tipo)) {

        $consulta = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, polo, count(id) as total_cursos FROM cursos WHERE polo = ? ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";
        $valueBindOne = $polo;

    }else if(empty($polo) && !empty($tipo)) {

        $consulta = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, polo, count(id) as total_cursos FROM cursos WHERE tipo = ? ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";
        $valueBindOne = $tipo;

    }else if (empty($polo) && empty($tipo)) {

        $consulta = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, polo, count(id) as total_cursos FROM cursos ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";        

    }else {

        $consulta = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, polo, count(id) as total_cursos FROM cursos WHERE polo = ? AND tipo = ? ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT $inicio, $limite";
        $valueBindOne = $polo;
        $valueBindTwo = $tipo;

    }

    $puxa_cursos = $con->prepare($consulta);

    if(!empty($valueBindOne) && empty($valueBindTwo)){
        $puxa_cursos->bindValue(1, $valueBindOne);
    }else{
        $puxa_cursos->bindValue(1, $valueBindOne);
        $puxa_cursos->bindValue(2, $valueBindTwo);
    }

    $puxa_cursos->execute();
    $cursos = $puxa_cursos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $paginas = ceil($puxa_cursos->rowCount() / $limite);

  }
```

Por fim você terá um objeto chamado cursos e poderá acessar seus valores de forma mais fácil, ex;

```
  foreach($cursos as $curso){
    echo $curso->id;
    echo $curso->nome;
    echo $curso->tipo;
    echo $curso->polo;
    echo $curso->total_cursos;
  }
```

Comment: Talisson, muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente, mas é seguro fazer dessa forma ou preciso fazer mais algum detalhe para garantir que eu não tenha problemas?

Comment: Notei apenas um problema, está retornando somente primeiro valor da consulta. E percebi que a função count está causando isso

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos você pode eliminá-la pois já usamos a função rowCount pra saber o total da consulta.

Comment: Sim, eu sei. Mas o problema é que se eu contabilizar com o rowCount ele vai me retornar apenas o número de resultados que estariam na primeira página. Preciso que contabilize todos os resultados para calcular numero de paginas

Comment: Achei a seguinte a alternativa e funcionou:
$contador = $con->query("SELECT count(*) FROM cursos")->fetchColumn();

Comment: Coloquei abaixo da $consulta, estaria errado fazer assim?